# Java garbage generator

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

I'd like to fine-tune GC for some big/hard-to-tweak/long-to-start Java application. I would like to have some java program which can be tuned to produce same patterns of memory allocation as my big program, so I could easily change GC settings and/or memory allocation patterns and see results.
Is there anything free ready-to-use Java app like that?

---

**Update/Clarification** Actual application is not-so-simple to test because it's input is feed over network in some format, it's some sort of server. I have memdumps of this application, so I can tell how often GC is run and of what type (minor/major). What I'd like to have is the app which I can fine-tune so what it will trigger GC in the same manner. And after that I would be able to fine-tune GC itself, so it will be performed faster/less often.

Comment: Um, what about testing GC settings with your actual application?

Comment: @Matt I've updated question, hopefully, my situation more clear now.

Comment: @Victor It's an interesting thought, but I fear it may be very difficult to come up with a test that faithfully replicates memory usage and GC patterns of any non-trivial app.

Comment: I agree with @aix: modelling memory allocation alone would be doable, but the GC depends a lot on a lot of other factors as well: which objects hang around for longer? Which object become eligible for GC right away? What's the life-time of each object? ...

Comment: @Joachim I have sources of my server as well, so I can tell (approx.) how created objects are distributed: which ones are going to die young, which ones are going to hang around for a while.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible. To accurately model your memory useage you just need a program that has the same inputs and outputs as your running program, and that processes it in the same way, where objects hang around as long. That sounds to me like it could only be your program. I don't even think you could mock out things like external services because you'd have to accurately model the behavior of those services as well as any custom drivers they might use (e.g. I've have to deal with mem. leaks in jdbc drivers - how could any mocked app find something like that?)